# How to resize and keep aspect ratio The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, image

This is straight out of the PHP manual except the jpg name.  I even used the php logo in the php manual.  I right clicked and saved image, just to be sure it wasn't my images.  I researched other questions in stack overflow, such as GD is enabled.  There was also talk of UTF-8 with BOM doesn't work.  I use Visual Studio Code with UTF-8 no BOM.  Here is the link to page.  http://cartrus.com/shops/scale_image.php?

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'php.jpg';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
$width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
$height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: Is that white space before `<?php` in your actual code?

Comment: I removed it just in case, no change

Comment: Is there maybe a parameter I need to enable in PHP, like GD is enabled?

Comment: My host is Godaddy if it matters

Comment: Your code is working with no problems for me, is the image in the same folder as the script ? does it has the same name as mentioned ? the code works...

Comment: The problem is it adds a single space to the output `20` - https://i.imgur.com/2tPmm6u.png, check in a hex editor. - fix that the image will work.

Comment: Rares, yes the image is in the same folder as the script, and yes the names are correct

Comment: Lawrence, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Lawrence, I see what you mean now.  but how do I correct that from happening?  Please and thank you

Comment: Dont output whitespace.. are you sure you have uploaded the current code. As it works fine now, since the edit..

Comment: Positive.  I assume my link doesn't work for you, and that you are using this code in your own test environment.  What if you submit your working code and I will copy and paste  This would eliminate any typos on my end.   Just a thought

Comment: Ok it's working now.  Weird, I copied and pasted my own code I posted on this post back into my page and it started working.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: Good, I replicated the issue, and compared it with yours and essentially you were doing - https://i.imgur.com/RpwJQfu.png - It's impossible to say here copy this as you may copy with additional spaces ;p - **no whitespace** else its part of the binary image, which wont work. If you enabled error reporting you would of seen within the hex code *headers already sent* php warning.

Comment: Good info Lawrence,  So a white space can confuse it that much. Thanks again